# can RegularExpression and StringLength attributes be used at same time?

Tags: validation, asp.net-core, attributes

Trying to validate a password field in ASP.Net Core.
I'd like to have to separated messages if the password does not match a regular expression and if it does not match a certain length.

So far, I tried this on my data model:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Le champs est obligatoire")]
[StringLength(30, MinimumLength = 10, ErrorMessage = "Password must contain from 10 to 30 characters")]
[RegularExpression("^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\\d.*)(?=.*\\W.*)[a-zA-Z0-9\\S]{10,30}$", ErrorMessage ="Password must contain at least 1 uppercase, 1 lowercase, 1 digit and 1 special character")]
```

But it seems that the StringLength attribute is never reached.

If I try different password like for example : `P@ss1!` I get the error message from the Regex attribute, but not from the StringLength attribute.

Of course, if I remove the RegularExpression attribute, StringLength attribute works just fine..

Any clue on this would be nice :)

EDIT :

```
<form asp-controller="Account" asp-action="EnterNewPassword" method="post">
                        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                        <input type="hidden" asp-for="ReturnUrl" />

                        <input asp-for="Token" type="hidden" />
                        <input asp-for="Email" type="hidden" />

                        <div class="col-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label asp-for="Password">Nouveau mot de passe</label>
                                <div class="password">
                                    <input asp-for="Password" type="password" class="form-control" /><i class="icon-eye" data-js-showPassword=""></i>
                                    <span asp-validation-for="Password" class="validation-error"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label asp-for="ConfirmPassword">Confirmation du mot de passe</label>
                                <div class="password">
                                    <input asp-for="ConfirmPassword" type="password" class="form-control" /><i class="icon-eye" data-js-showPassword=""></i>
                                    <span asp-validation-for="ConfirmPassword" class="validation-error"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12 text-center">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn">Mettre à jour</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

Comment: Your code works fine and as expected for me. Although your regular expression does not work the way you expect it to, test it on https://regexr.com/. I would guess that the way you are displaying your validation summary is where the issue is at.

Comment: Please post your code to help reproduce . In addition , `P@ss1!` should work with `Password must contain at least 1 uppercase, 1 lowercase, 1 digit and 1 special character` . You might try regex like `^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*\W).*$`

Comment: Thanks for you time guys. Just added to the original post.